# ARKit Continuously get Camera Real World Position

Tags: ios, arkit

This is the first time I am creating an ARKit app, and also not very familiar with iOS development, however I am trying to achieve something relitively simple...

All the the app needs to do is get the world position of the phone and send it continously to a rest api.

I am using the default ARKit project in Xcode, and am able to get the phone's position with the following function in ViewController.swift:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

        if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {

            let plane = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z))
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.75)

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
            planeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(planeAnchor.center.x, planeAnchor.center.x, planeAnchor.center.z)
            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        }


        guard let pointOfView = sceneView.pointOfView else { return }
        let transform = pointOfView.transform
        let orientation = SCNVector3(-transform.m31, -transform.m32, transform.m33)
        let location = SCNVector3(transform.m41, transform.m42, transform.m43)
        let currentPositionOfCamera = SCNVector3(orientation.x + location.x, orientation.y + location.y, orientation.z + location.z)
        print(currentPositionOfCamera)


    }
```

this function works as expected, in renders a plane in the view and prints the position, **but only once**

I need to get the phone's position as it is moved, I tried to add:
updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval
to the function definition, but after doing this even the plane was not rendered any longer.

How can I continuously get the phone's position vector?

TIA